# How do I select the default value in select list in cshtml?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have created a dropdown using select2 in cshtml, which allows to selects multiple data from a dropdown.

```
SelectList studentList = new SelectList(Model.CourseStudents.Select(_ => _.Student).OrderBy(_ => _.DisplayName), "Id", "DisplayName", null);

<div>
        <div class="form-group row-5 col-2">
            <label asp-for="AssignmentStudents">Students</label>
            <select data-placeholder="Select specific students. Leave empty for all students" asp-for="AssignmentStudents" id="UserId" name="UserId" asp-items="studentList" multiple class="js-select2">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above code has created a page in a form, after selecting the values from the dropdown, the Id of the Users in the options goes to the controller and is saved to the database that's fine, but how can I when I redirect to the page I need to display the name in the dropdown that was selected while submitting the form how can I do this?

For Example:-

While Submitting the form let's say I selected two names A and B and its Id is 1 and 2 respectively. In the controller, the values go as `1,2` in `model.AssignmentStudents` while submitting the form, but using the same value while redirecting to the form, the name is not displayed in the dropdown. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @Biraj Dahal,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo

```
public class SelectModel : PageModel
{
    //....
    [BindProperty]
    public int[] AssignmentStudents { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        SelectList studentList = new SelectList(Model.CourseStudents.Select(_ => _.Student).OrderBy(_ => _.DisplayName), "Id", "DisplayName", null);

        ViewData["studentList"] = studentList;
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostTest(int[] AssignmentStudents)
    {
      foreach(var i in AssignmentStudents)
        {
            //...do your logic
        }
      SelectList studentList = new SelectList(Model.CourseStudents.Select(_ => _.Student).OrderBy(_ => _.DisplayName), "Id", "DisplayName", null);
       
      ViewData["studentList"] = studentList;

       return Page();
    }

}
```

Page:

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Test">
<div>
    <div class="form-group row-5 col-2">
        <label asp-for="AssignmentStudents">Students</label>
        <select data-placeholder="Select specific students. Leave empty for all students" asp-for="AssignmentStudents" id="UserId" asp-items=@ViewBag.studentList multiple class="js-select2">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```